# Nested arrow function typescript syntax

Tags: typescript, redux-thunk

```
export const asyncAction = (data: {
  param: string
}): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const apidata = await api({ param });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I get this error "No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'param'. Either declare one or provide an initializer."

Comment: `parma` is not `param`

Comment: @crashmstr that was a typo

Comment: You're not destructuring (or otherwise extracting) `param` out of `data`, you'd have to do e.g. `await api({ param: data.param })`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I see. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to destructure the `param` property, you'll have to put the destructured object syntax to the left of the parameter type definition, like so:

```
export const asyncAction = ({
  param,
}: {
  param: string;
}): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
  // ...
```

But in this case, if the one parameter is indeed an object with only a `param` property, destructuring doesn't help, because you're later creating an object with a `param` property to pass to `api`:

```
export const asyncAction = (data: { param: string; }): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const apidata = await api(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outerscope method has a parameter called data with param property. In your inner scope method you are trying to access param without data.param

if should be:

```
export const asyncAction = (data: {
    param: string
}): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const apidata = await api({ param: data.param });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In `api({ param });` you are trying to access `param` that's stored in `data`. You need to "unpack" it from `data` first, like this: `const param = data.param;`, only then you can use it.

```
export const asyncAction = (data: {
  param: string
}): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
  const param = data.param;
  try {
    const apidata = await api({ param });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```